# Column Constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server bit column constraint, 1 row = 1, all others 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810615/sql-server-bit-column-constraint-1-row-1-all-others-0)

Hi all,

Say I have a table called **TableA** containing a `BIT` field. Is there any way I can enforce only one row in a table to be ever set at `1`?

**Edit:** No triggers, please!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`CHECK` constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint).

Comment: From your link, "Most database management systems restrict check constraints to a single row" - how would you propose that a CHECK constraint be able to determine whether it's column value being 1 is valid without consulting other rows? In e.g. SQL Server, there are kludges using UDFs, but they're not 100% there, usually.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I suggest you read further: "Such constraints are not truly table check constraints but rather row check constraints.". And they exist in SQL Server properly, not as UDF kludges: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

Comment: but the necessary constraint in this case needs to assert the truth or otherwise about the state of the table as a whole - that exactly one row has ColumnX = 1. That is not possible with a CHECK constraint (at least in SQL Server). And the solutions to this problem are well known, as linked to dups by myself and Joe - you use an indexed view or a filtered index.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckTestTableFlag]()
RETURNS int
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval int
    SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE Flag = 1;
    RETURN @retval;
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [chkFlag] CHECK  ([dbo].[CheckTestTableFlag]()<= 1 )
```

GO