# SQL Server check constraints - only one particular value per group

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I need some help with adding a check in one of the added columns to the existing tables. I am not sure if that will be a computed column or check constraint.

Table changes to Products table, new column is `IsDefault` and existing column name is `banId`. `IsDefault` value is 0  but when turned to 1 is only possible for one per `banId` column.

```
IsDefault BIT (only one per banId, default 0)
```

I need to add it to this code to add that one per `banId` condition

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].products
    ADD IsDefault BIT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_products_IsDefault DEFAULT 0 

ProductId   banId           IsDefault
-------------------------------------
1             1                   0
2             1                   1
3             1                   0
4             2                   0
5             2                   0
6             2                   0
7             3                   1
8             4                   1
9             4                   0
```

Comment: use a unique filtered index.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776793/6167855) on that duplicate question

Comment: I saw that post @MartinSmith, it recommends placing a filtered Index, I placed that and it does that work but this sounds more like a constraint or a check in a table. My understanding of indexes is that they are used for improving table scan's and search results not for checking values added to the table. Not sure if thats solution makes complete sense.

Comment: SQL has a concept of unique constraints. These are similar in concept to other types of constraints. In SQL Server if you create a unique constraint it also creates a unique index so it can enforce it efficiently. Here you are just creating the index yourself to enforce your desired rule.

Comment: @MartinSmith, thank you so much, now it makes more sense. Learned something new on this today.